# CSS padding right and text-align right don't work together in table cell

Tags: html, css, padding, text-align, cellpadding

```
td.myclass{
    width: 6em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to have the text in the cell right aligned, 2em from the right cell border.

This doesn't work.

The text is right aligned but it stays stuck on the right border (the `padding-right` instruction has no effect).
Any idea why? How can I make it work? I'm using Firefox 22.

Comment: working fine in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/qhPkH/

Answer (score 1):

for text position use

```
padding-right : 2em;
```